# Using a joker when you can't make any other moves

Tags: rummikub

Consider the following scenario:

1) There are no more tiles to be taken.
2) I have 9 tiles (none that form a run or set)

...except I have a joker and 2 tiles in hand, which would make a run.

Do I have to use that joker or can I pass my turn?

Comment: I have never even come close to running out of tiles in this game.  I am not positive but I don't think this situation could actually happen since at some point almost every single tile becomes playable.

Comment: @Styxsksu unlikely as it is, consider a four player game with each player having drawn both the ones of one colour, the twos of the next, the threes of the next, the fours of the last, then the fives of the first and so on up to the thirteens (of the first colour). Even getting both jokers wouldn't get a player enough points to get onto the table.

Comment: If you only have 9 tiles that implies that you have already gone down with some number of points since you start with 14 tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could pass but I wouldn't recommend it since if everyone passes the game is over.

In this rare case the rules state that if all players pass then the game ends and the player with the lowest score is consider the winner.  Since the Joker is worth the most point I would probably play it to get the point out of my hand at this point.

Comment: I found a similar question on BGG, that refer to both sets of rule books for this question since I don't have a copy of the game anymore.